# @mui/material Autocomplete Typescript error

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm working on an Autocomplete field that utilizes react-hook-form. Currently, it seems to be working as expected, however I'm receiving the following TS error:

```
Type '{ autoComplete: true; disableClearable: true; fullWidth: true; options: { value: MeasuringSystem; label: string; }[]; onChange: (e: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, v: { ...; }) => void; ... 5 more ...; ref: RefCallBack; }' is not assignable to type 'AutocompleteProps<{ value: MeasuringSystem; label: string; }, undefined, true, undefined, "div">'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | { value: MeasuringSystem; label: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ value: MeasuringSystem; label: string; } | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ value: MeasuringSystem; label: string; } | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```tsx
export enum MeasuringSystem {
  Imperial = 'IMPERIAL',
  Metric = 'METRIC',
}

interface MeasuringSystemOption {
  value: MeasuringSystem;
  label: string;
}

interface DefaultValues {
  firstName: string | undefined;
  lastName: string | undefined;
  trailName: string | undefined;
  measuringSystem: MeasuringSystemOption;
  address1: string | undefined;
  address2: string | undefined;
  city: string | undefined;
  state: string | undefined;
  country: string | undefined;
}

const measuringSystemOptions = [
  { value: MeasuringSystem.Imperial, label: 'Imperial (lbs, oz)' },
  { value: MeasuringSystem.Metric, label: 'Metric (kg, g)' },
];

const Profile: React.FC = () => {
  ...other code

  const defaultSystem = measuringSystemOptions.find(
    opt => opt.value === currentUser?.measuringSystem
  );
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: currentUser?.firstName ?? '',
      lastName: currentUser?.lastName ? currentUser.lastName : '',
      measuringSystem: defaultSystem || '',
      address1: currentUser?.address1 ?? '',
      address2: currentUser?.address2 ? currentUser.address2 : '',
      city: currentUser?.city ? currentUser.city : '',
      state: currentUser?.state ? currentUser.state : '',
      country: currentUser?.country ? currentUser.country : '',
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const resetUser = {
      firstName: currentUser?.firstName ?? '',
      lastName: currentUser?.lastName ?? '',
      address1: currentUser?.address1 ?? '',
      address2: currentUser?.address2 ?? '',
      city: currentUser?.city ?? '',
      state: currentUser?.state ?? '',
      country: currentUser?.country ?? '',
      measuringSystem: defaultSystem ?? '',
    } as any;
    if (currentUser) reset(resetUser);
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="measuringSystem"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Autocomplete // <-- TS Error
            {...field}
            autoComplete
            disableClearable
            fullWidth
            options={measuringSystemOptions}
            onChange={(e, v) => field.onChange(v)}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              option.value === value.value
            }
            renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                inputRef={field.ref}
                error={!!errors?.measuringSystem}
                helperText={(errors?.measuringSystem as any)?.message}
                label="Preferred Measuring System"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                InputProps={{
                  ...params.InputProps,
                  startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <PublicIcon
                        color={
                          errors?.measuringSystem ? 'error' : 'inherit'
                        }
                      />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        )}
      />  
    </div>
  );
};
```

I get the gist of what the error is all about, I'm just not sure how to actually go about fixing this?

Comment: What is the type of `MeasuringSystem`? Can you reproduce the error in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-hx82c?file=/demo.tsx)?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I updated the post with the defined enum at the top. I also attempted to replicate it in the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-uo3xk?file=/demo.tsx) but I'm receiving a different error within the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop.

Comment: You can type the value in the form like this: `useForm<FormInputs>`. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-ifuns?file=/demo.tsx) codesandbox.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I could do that! I ended up using the `DefaultValues` type definition to pass in to `useForm`, and changed the defaultValue to `measuringSystem: defaultSystem`, which seems to have fixed the errors. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NearHuscarl for the fix in the post comments. Here's what fixed it:

```tsx
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm<DefaultValues>({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: currentUser?.firstName ?? '',
      lastName: currentUser?.lastName ?? '',
      trailName: currentUser?.trailName ?? '',
      measuringSystem: defaultSystem,
      address1: currentUser?.address1 ?? '',
      address2: currentUser?.address2 ?? '',
      city: currentUser?.city ?? '',
      state: currentUser?.state ?? '',
      country: currentUser?.country ?? '',
    },
  });
```

I am passing in `<DefaultValues>` to the `useForm` definition, and then altering the `measuringSystem` so that it doesn't set to an empty string if undefined or null. Fixes all of the issues!